# Why is commit producing a 500 internal server error?

Tags: 2010, user-profile-property, application-pages

I am writing a WebMethod in an Application Page for a SharePoint 2010 site, that updates the current user's profile properties.

Web Method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string setProfileProperties(ProfileProperties data)
{
    if (data == null)
    {
        return "{\"result\": \"" + false + "\"}";
    }
    SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(context);
    string loginName = web.CurrentUser.LoginName;

    if (upm.UserExists(loginName))
    {
        UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile(loginName);
        profile[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].Value = data.email;
        profile[PropertyConstants.FirstName].Value = data.name;
        profile.Commit(); // error here!!
        return "{\"result\": \"" + true + "\"}";
    }
    return "{\"result\": \"" + false + "\"}";
}
```

NOTE: `ProfileProperties` is a custom object with fields such as `name` and `email`.

The data being passed in is already correct, yet when I commit the changes, I get a 500 server error. My assumption is permissions. Does anyone know how I can get my profile to save/commit changes? Thanks.

Comment: what is the value in loginname ? it should be in the format of `domain\user`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like server context is not available when you call the GetContext method.

Try below code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string setProfileProperties(ProfileProperties data)
{

    SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();

    SPWebApplication spWebApp = null;
    try
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            return "{\"result\": \"" + false + "\"}";
        }
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()     
        { 
            //Create a SPSite Object with a valid Site collection address
            using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite("https://sitecollection"))
            {
                //Open the web object
                using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    //Create the Web Application object from the current site
                    spWebApp = spSite.WebApplication;    

                    //Create the server context
                    ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(spSite);

                    //Update the HttpHandlerSPWeb with the web object and 
                    //the Microsoft.Office.ServerContext with the server context
                    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                    {
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] == null)
                            HttpContext.Current.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = spWeb;
                        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["Microsoft.Office.ServerContext"] == null)
                            HttpContext.Current.Items["Microsoft.Office.ServerContext"] = context;
                    }

                    //Create the user profile object from the context object
                    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);                                

                    string loginName = web.CurrentUser.LoginName; // account format should be "domain\\user";

                    if (profileManager.UserExists(loginName))
                    {
                        UserProfile profile = upm.GetUserProfile(loginName);
                        profile[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].Value = data.email;
                        profile[PropertyConstants.FirstName].Value = data.name;
                        profile.Commit();
                        return "{\"result\": \"" + true + "\"}";
                    }

                    return "{\"result\": \"" + false + "\"}";
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        return "{\"result\": \"" + false + "\"}";
    }       

}
```

Reference - [Faking SPContext](https://solutionizing.net/2009/02/16/faking-spcontext/)

[Update user profile properties programmatically](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b06d7074-3458-47a5-8578-f43fb26de667/update-userprofile-programmatically?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

Also, ensure that "Allow user to edit values for this property is set to true".

[image]

Comment: This code gives me an access denied exception when changing the FormDigestSettings to false.

Comment: Can you check updated answer ?

Comment: Where is that setting within the site? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Go to central admin > manage service application > user profile application > user profile properties. There you will find the properties. Click on work email or first name and edit it. There you will find this setting.

Comment: I've made it so both profile properties are editable as per your suggestion, however I'm still getting an access denied when changing the FormDigestSettings to false.

Comment: Did you try updated code?